# Adding tear down method to junit test suite after loading class dynamically

Tags: java, junit, runtime, test-suite

I load all test dynamically in to a test suite like this:

```
@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public final class MyTestSuite {
    public static TestSuite suite() {               
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        for (Test test : findAllTestCasesRuntime()) { // returns a list of JUnit4TestAdapter(Class.forName(fileName))
          suite.addTest(test);
        }    
        return suite;
      }
}
```

I would like to add a @after method to the testsuite that is run for all tests. Today each test has this method doing the exact same thing. I have tried to subclass testsuite and add an @after method but with no luck.

Comment: Are you looking for `@AfterClass`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have tried different annotations when I extended the TestSuite class and non of them got executed. Its more that I don't know were I should put the method I want to run.

Comment: You put the `@AfterClass` method in the same class as your tests.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't want that because it will be the exact same code in all the classes. Please see my answer below. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found:
I created a base test class:

```
@Ignore
public class MyTestBase {
    @After
    public void runsAfterEveryTestFromBaseClass() {
        //code
    }   
}
```

My actual test class now extends this class so the code in the question now looks like this:

```
@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public final class MyTestSuite extends MyTestBase{
    public static TestSuite suite() {               
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        for (Test test : findAllTestCasesRuntime()) { // returns a list of JUnit4TestAdapter(Class.forName(fileName))
          suite.addTest(test);
        }    
        return suite;
      }
}
```

Now the code in the runsAfterEveryTestFromBaseClass method runs after every test.